# Swift function returns too early

Tags: swift, xcode, function, asynchronous

In the following code, the function will return "Var" before the *checkDayEqualsToDoc* function can return a bool and change "Var". I've tried looking a lot of places for an answer and I keep seeing the same thing... use closures... use completions... etc. Are those the correct things to use in this case? And if so, how would I implement that?

```
func dotMarker(shouldShowOnDayView dayView: DayView) -> Bool {
    var Var:Bool = false
    let dDate = dayView.date.convertedDate()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.checkDayEqualsToDoc(date: dayView.date.convertedDate()!){ (bool, error) in
            Var = bool
        }
    }
    return Var
}
```

Here is the *checkDayEqualsToDoc* function:

```
func checkDayEqualsToDoc(date: Date, completionHandler:@escaping (Bool, Error?) -> Void){
    var Variable = false
    let tomorrow = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: date)
    let btRef = db.collection("bomtracking")

    let myDate = date
    let startOfDate = myDate.startOfDay
    let endOfDate = myDate.endOfDay
    let dateAtBeginning = date.firstSecondInDay()
    let dateAtEnd = date.lastSecondInDay()
    let query = btRef
        .whereField("UID", isEqualTo: UID)
        .whereField("timestamp", isGreaterThan: dateAtBeginning)
        .whereField("timestamp", isLessThan: dateAtEnd)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        query.getDocuments(){ (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents{
                    let curValid = document.get("valid")
                    let curValidA = Bool(curValid as! Bool)
                    if curValidA == true {
                        let curdoc = document.get("timestamp")
                        let curdocDate = self.dateConversion(curdoc as! Date)
                        let dateConverted = self.dateConversion(date)
                        if curdocDate == dateConverted {
                            Variable = true
                            break
                        }
                        else {
                            Variable = false
                        }
                    }
                }
                completionHandler(Variable, nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: yes, you need to use @escaping closure.

Answer (score 0):

When a function is asynchronous, you don't want to return the value, you want to pass it back in a completion.

```
func dotMarker(shouldShowOn dayView: DayView, completion: @escaping (Bool)->Void) {
    let dDate = dayView.date.convertedDate()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.checkDayEqualsToDoc(date: dayView.date.convertedDate()!){ (bool, error) in
            completion(bool)
        }
    }
}
```

Is what this would look like. When the `checkDaysEqualsToDoc` finishes, it calls its own completion, which is where the `(bool, error) in` comes from. In that completion, you have the value you want `dotMarker` to "return", so you call your completion handler with that bool value.

Two things though:

1. Why are you putting `checkDayEqualsToDoc` in an async thread?
2. Variable names should always start lowercased, and should be more descriptive than `Var`